# using await Task.Delay in a for kills performance

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

Let's say I want to start roughly N tasks per second distributed equally.

So I tried this:

```
public async Task Generate(int numberOfCallsPerSecond) 
{
    var delay = TimeSpan.FromMiliseconds(1000/numberOfCallsPerSecond); // a call should happen every 1000 / numberOfCallsPerSecond miliseconds
    for (int i=0; i < numberOfcallsPerSecond; i++) 
    {
        Task t = Call();  // don't wait for result here
        await Task.Delay(delay);
    }
}
```

At first I expected this to run in 1 second but  for `numberOfCallsPerSecond = 100` it takes `16 seconds` on my 12 core CPU. 
It seems the await Task.Delay adds a lot of overhead (of course without it in place generation of the calls happens in 3ms.

I didn't expect that await would add so much overhead in this scenario. Is this normal?

EDIT:

Please forget about the Call(). Running this code shows similiar result:

```
public async Task Generate(int numberOfCallsPerSecond) 
{
var delay = TimeSpan.FromMiliseconds(1000/numberOfCallsPerSecond); // a call should happen every 1000 / numberOfCallsPerSecond miliseconds
for (int i=0; i < numberOfcallsPerSecond; i++) 
{
    await Task.Delay(delay);
 }
}
```

I tried to run it with `numberOfCallsPerSecond = 500` and it takes around 10 seconds, I expected `Generate` to take roughly 1 second, not 10 times more

Comment: Could you give some code for the Call method ? Are you sure this method doesn't takes time before returning the Task object ?

Comment: Your new result of 500 calls in around 10 seconds agrees pretty well with the scheduler quantum.

Comment: Hi guys, please forget about the Call() method, check my EDIT

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Task.Delay` is lightweight but not accurate.  Since the loop without delay completes much faster, it sounds like your thread is going idle and using an OS sleep to wait for the timer to elapse.  The timer is checked according to the OS thread scheduling quantum (in the same interrupt handler which performs thread pre-emption), which is 16ms by default.

You can reduce the quantum with `timeBeginPeriod`, but a better (more power efficient) approach if you need rate limiting rather than exact timing is to keep track of elapsed time (the `Stopwatch` class is good for this) and number of calls made, and only delay when calls made have caught up to elapsed time.  The overall effect is that your thread will wake up ~60 times per second, and start a few work items each time it does.  If your CPU becomes busy with something else, you'll start extra work items when you get control back -- although it's also pretty straightforward to cap the number of items started at once, if that's what you need.

```
public async Task Generate(int numberOfCallsPerSecond) 
{
    var elapsed = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var delay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000/numberOfCallsPerSecond); // a call should happen every 1000 / numberOfCallsPerSecond milliseconds
    for (int i=0; i < numberOfcallsPerSecond; i++) 
    {
        Call();  // don't wait for result here
        int expectedI = elapsed.Elapsed.TotalSeconds * numberOfCallsPerSecond;
        if (i > expectedI) await Task.Delay(delay);
    }
}
```

Comment: hey, great answer that explains it :). I was really surprised by the overhead. Will give your solution a try. +1

Comment: `await Task.Delay()` doesn't cause the thread to sleep for the given time. Instead, it uses a timer and schedules the continuation to execute when the timer elapses. So what matters here is the resolution of the timer, not that of sleep. Though both are 16 ms by default, which is why the observed behavior is the same as what you're describing.

Comment: @svick: I did not say that `Task.Delay()` sleeps the thread.  The task dispatching loop will if there are no tasks ready.

Comment: So, if I used a more precise timer in a custom version of `Delay()`, you would expect the same ~16 ms delay for each `await`? [Because that's not what happens.](https://gist.github.com/svick/251f233d856a763fcf16)

Comment: @svick: You're right, it's not actually that thread wakeup is required to be slow.  It *is* the scheduler quantum that matters, though, because the same HW timer interrupt is used for thread scheduling and timers.  That scheduler ISR is making the thread runnable because a timer on the thread expired.  With your "precise timer", the future is making the thread runnable.

Answer (score 4):

My psychic debugger says your `Call` method has a significant synchronous part (i.e the part before an `await`) which takes time to execute synchronously.

If you want the `Generate` method only to "fire up" these `Call` calls and have them run concurrently (including the synchronous parts) you need to offload them to a `ThreadPool` thread using `Task.Run`:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => Call());
await Task.Delay(delay);
```

---

`Task.Delay` adds almost no overhead. It uses a `System.Threading.Timer` internally that requires very little resources.

Comment: The first revision of the question mentioned that "without `Task.Delay` in place the code finishes in 3ms" which seems to rule out this explanation

Answer (score -3):

If you use a timespan with Task.Delay(), it'll kill the CPU. Use an integer and it wont. True story. no idea why.

Comment: Could you post some code/benchmark? Would be a nice addition.

Comment: I'll try to remember to put one together when I find some time. It was something I discovered while writing a log tailer some time last year.

Comment: Have you found the time yet? I'm curious about this lol

Comment: for all fools who venture here, starting 10,000 Task.Delays() had no visible impact on CPU utilisation. Starting a million Task.Delays() caused CPU to spike a small amount, but it spiked equally for both timespan and int - OP's issue was either hardware specific or it has been patched sometime in the last 7 years

Comment: @TheLemon I honestly forgot about this, after showing a bunch of times that there was a notable different, I left it as int and moved on. Iirc this was on .NET 4.5 and the problem was consistent on at least a few different systems. fwiw, I've done delays with TimeSpan since then with no noticeable issues.